# FEST: Getting a component by his class (inherited from a basic component)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, testing, fest

I have this code:

```
   //FrameFixture frame = (...got it from window, main frame...)
   JTableFixture table = frame.table(new GenericTypeMatcher<JTable>(JTable.class) {
         @Override protected boolean isMatching(JTable table) {
            return (table instanceof myTreeTable); 
         }  
    });
```

Isnt there any better kind of syntactic sugar for fetching a component by his .class (inheriting from a basic component)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need implementation of `ComponentMatcher` then [TypeMatcher](http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/core/TypeMatcher.html) can do matching based on type.

However `TypeMatcher` cannot be used in case of [ContainerFixture.table](http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/fixture/ContainerFixture.html#table%28org.fest.swing.core.GenericTypeMatcher%29) methods as they require `GenericTypeMatcher`.

`TypeMatcher` and `GenericTypeMatcher` both implement `ComponentMatcher` but aren't in the same hierarchy.

`GenericTypeMatcher` is abstract, so you have to provide an implementation. You could get away with your own extension if needed, ie:

```
class ConcreteTypeMatcher<T extends Component> extends GenericTypeMatcher<T> {
    Class<T> type;

    public ConcreteTypeMatcher(Class<T> supportedType) {
        super(supportedType);
        this.type = supportedType;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isMatching(T arg) {
        return type.isInstance(arg);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
JTableFixture table = frame.table(
      new ConcreteTypeMatcher<myTreeTable>(myTreeTable.class));
```

Comment: Excellent answer, like previous one. Thank you very much, Max